# What should be changed from using unactivated evernote api to using activated evernote api?

Tags: ios, evernote

I had used sandbox to connect with evernote, for example:

```
NSString * const consumerKey  = @"myKey";
NSString * const consumerSecret = @"mySecret";

NSString * const userStoreUri = @"https://sandbox.evernote.com/edam/user";
NSString * const noteStoreUriBase = @"https://sandbox.evernote.com/edam/note/"; 

NSString * const applicationName = @"myApp";
NSString * const applicationVersion = @"0.1";
```

Now I have requested to connect with normal evernote account, and Evernote Team have activated my evernote api, but I found that I can only connect with sandbox account.

What should be changed from using unactivated evernote api to using activated evernote api? consumerKey? or consumerSecret? or userStoreUri? or noteStoreUriBase?

Comment: Hi ybbaigo , i am trying to generate the consumerKey, consumerSecret  but i did find how to generate .. PLease Guide me @ybbaigo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your URL stems from "https://sandbox.evernote.com" to "https:/www.evernote.com".

Comment: Hi Seth , i am trying to generate the consumerKey, consumerSecret  but i did find how to generate .. PLease Guide me @Seth

Comment: To create an API key visit http://dev.evernote.com/documentation/cloud/ and click on "Register for an API key".